# What does this Operator in SAP ABAP means "(+)="

Tags: abap

```
SELECT KNVV.MANDT, KNVV.VTWEG
INTO :V-MANDT, V:-KUNNR
FROM KNA1
WHERE KNVP.MANDT +(=) KNVV.MANDT
```

I wanted to transform this code in SQL Format but I don't know what this Operator `+=` does.

First I thought it is similar to Joins in SQL but I don't get the same Data rows in SAP. I really appreciate It if someone could help me with my problem.

Comment: you are coding in HANA? It looks like SQLScript

Comment: This looks like Oracle. It has nothing to do with ABAP as this looks like a native sql query in ABAP (EXEC SQL. ENDEXEC.)